# Cannot Keyframe - Vers.2.83?

Tags: animation

In VSE, I cannot get any of the keyframe properties to work!

Example: In the VSE, using Saturation, at Frame 1, I slider to "0" and select "I", then move to frame 30, slider to "1" and select "I".  This only changes the "0" at Frame 1 to also be "1".

Example 2: In the VSE, I've added a text layer and want it to scroll.  At Frame 1, have the Y location set to "Bottom" with a parameter of -0.01, and then select "I" (turns yellow); I then move to frame 30 and set the Y location to 0.87, select "I" and it turns yellow. However, the "-0.01" at Frame 1 has now also changed to "0.87", and there is no animation!!@

Is this something you can no longer do in 2.83?

Comment: I do not think that they removed keyframing in 2.83 which would be ... let's just call it stupid. I rather think that it is a bug since this version is still in beta.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and I redownloaded Blender 2.83. I opened my file, and all the keyframing works the way it's supposed to. Proabably a bug.

Comment: You guys were both correct.  I "re-downloaded" another copy, and it works as intended!  Thanks for the input!!